OpenShift eventlistener not triggered by GitHub webhook
I'm trying to learn OpenShift from RedHat. Unfortunately I can't get the pipeline to run when I push changes to my repository in GitHub.
My pipeline is quite simple. It clones my git repository and then runs maven clean.
What I want is that the pipeline to run when I push changes to my repository.
I get the following error in the log when the webhook is triggered.
{"severity":"error","timestamp":"2024-10-02T06:30:37.301Z","logger":"eventlistener", "caller":"sink/sink.go:606", "message":"problem creating obj: &errors.errorString{s:\"couldn't create resource with group version kind \\\"tekton.dev/v1beta1, Resource=pipelineruns\\\": admission webhook \\\"validation.webhook.pipeline.tekton.dev\\\" denied the request: validation failed: expected exactly one, got neither: spec.workspaces[0].configmap, spec.workspaces[0].emptydir, spec.workspaces[0].persistentvolumeclaim, spec.workspaces[0].secret, spec.workspaces[0].volumeclaimtemplate\"}","commit":"f76be74","eventlistener":"petclinic-eventlistener","namespace":"max-sjogren-dev","/triggers-eventid":"98754b42-99fc-4ad7-bd39-d56eafc6d129","eventlistenerUID":"10a95c7d-1f54-417f-9b8f-c6799f58bf5d","/triggers-eventid":"98754b42-99fc-4ad7-bd39-d56eafc6d129","/trigger":"petclinic-triggerbinding"}
{"severity":"error","timestamp":"2024-10-02T06:30:37.301Z","logger":"eventlistener","caller":"sink/sink.go:446","message":"couldn't create resource with group version kind \"tekton.dev/v1beta1, Resource=pipelineruns\": admission webhook \"validation.webhook.pipeline.tekton.dev\" denied the request: validation failed: expected exactly one, got neither: spec.workspaces[0].configmap, spec.workspaces[0].emptydir, spec.workspaces[0].persistentvolumeclaim, spec.workspaces[0].secret, spec.workspaces[0].volumeclaimtemplate","commit":"f76be74","eventlistener":"petclinic-eventlistener","namespace":"max-sjogren-dev","/triggers-eventid":"98754b42-99fc-4ad7-bd39-d56eafc6d129","eventlistenerUID":"10a95c7d-1f54-417f-9b8f-c6799f58bf5d","/triggers-eventid":"98754b42-99fc-4ad7-bd39-d56eafc6d129","/trigger":"petclinic-triggerbinding"}

Those are hard to read; the extracted error messages are:

problem creating obj: &errors.errorString{s:"couldn't create resource with
group version kind "tekton.dev/v1beta1, Resource=pipelineruns": admission
webhook "validation.webhook.pipeline.tekton.dev" denied the request:
validation failed: expected exactly one, got neither:
spec.workspaces[0].configmap, spec.workspaces[0].emptydir,
spec.workspaces[0].persistentvolumeclaim, spec.workspaces[0].secret,
spec.workspaces[0].volumeclaimtemplate"}

And:

couldn't create resource with group version kind "tekton.dev/v1beta1,
Resource=pipelineruns": admission webhook
"validation.webhook.pipeline.tekton.dev" denied the request: validation
failed: expected exactly one, got neither: spec.workspaces[0].configmap,
spec.workspaces[0].emptydir, spec.workspaces[0].persistentvolumeclaim,
spec.workspaces[0].secret, spec.workspaces[0].volumeclaimtemplate

To save time I use Postman instead of editing files and push in to my repository. I use Postman with the following payload. The post was considered spam, so I changed all http(s):// to ... and @ to 'at' in the postman payload.
{
    "ref": "refs/heads/main",
    "before": "4ab5c24f8ce2a6206abdcde56d48c4f80fa26dda",
    "after": "d191bc41b096d8a3535b4df28af94bc68a5700c2",
    "repository": {
        "id": 856303118,
        "node_id": "R_kgDOMwomDg",
        "name": "spring-petclinic",
        "full_name": "MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic",
        "private": false,
        "owner": {
            "name": "MaxSjogren",
            "email": "BOFH'at'example.com",
            "login": "MaxSjogren",
            "id": 181346483,
            "node_id": "U_kgDOCs8gsw",
            "avatar_url": "...avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/181346483?v=4",
            "gravatar_id": "",
            "url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren",
            "html_url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren",
            "followers_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/followers",
            "following_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/following{/other_user}",
            "gists_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/gists{/gist_id}",
            "starred_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
            "subscriptions_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/subscriptions",
            "organizations_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/orgs",
            "repos_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/repos",
            "events_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/events{/privacy}",
            "received_events_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/received_events",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": false
        },
        "html_url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic",
        "description": "A sample Spring-based application",
        "fork": true,
        "url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic",
        "forks_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/forks",
        "keys_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/keys{/key_id}",
        "collaborators_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/collaborators{/collaborator}",
        "teams_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/teams",
        "hooks_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/hooks",
        "issue_events_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/issues/events{/number}",
        "events_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/events",
        "assignees_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/assignees{/user}",
        "branches_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/branches{/branch}",
        "tags_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/tags",
        "blobs_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/git/blobs{/sha}",
        "git_tags_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/git/tags{/sha}",
        "git_refs_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/git/refs{/sha}",
        "trees_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/git/trees{/sha}",
        "statuses_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/statuses/{sha}",
        "languages_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/languages",
        "stargazers_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/stargazers",
        "contributors_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/contributors",
        "subscribers_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/subscribers",
        "subscription_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/subscription",
        "commits_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/commits{/sha}",
        "git_commits_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/git/commits{/sha}",
        "comments_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/comments{/number}",
        "issue_comment_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/issues/comments{/number}",
        "contents_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/contents/{+path}",
        "compare_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/compare/{base}...{head}",
        "merges_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/merges",
        "archive_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/{archive_format}{/ref}",
        "downloads_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/downloads",
        "issues_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/issues{/number}",
        "pulls_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/pulls{/number}",
        "milestones_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/milestones{/number}",
        "notifications_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
        "labels_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/labels{/name}",
        "releases_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/releases{/id}",
        "deployments_url": "...api.github.com/repos/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/deployments",
        "created_at": 1726138419,
        "updated_at": "2024-10-01T09:34:52Z",
        "pushed_at": 1727780112,
        "git_url": "git://github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic.git",
        "ssh_url": "git'at'github.com:MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic.git",
        "clone_url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic.git",
        "svn_url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic",
        "homepage": "",
        "size": 7759,
        "stargazers_count": 0,
        "watchers_count": 0,
        "language": "CSS",
        "has_issues": false,
        "has_projects": true,
        "has_downloads": true,
        "has_wiki": false,
        "has_pages": false,
        "has_discussions": false,
        "forks_count": 0,
        "mirror_url": null,
        "archived": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "open_issues_count": 0,
        "license": {
            "key": "apache-2.0",
            "name": "Apache License 2.0",
            "spdx_id": "Apache-2.0",
            "url": "...api.github.com/licenses/apache-2.0",
            "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTI="
        },
        "allow_forking": true,
        "is_template": false,
        "web_commit_signoff_required": false,
        "topics": [],
        "visibility": "public",
        "forks": 0,
        "open_issues": 0,
        "watchers": 0,
        "default_branch": "main",
        "stargazers": 0,
        "master_branch": "main"
    },
    "pusher": {
        "name": "MaxSjogren",
        "email": "BOFH'at'example.com"
    },
    "sender": {
        "login": "MaxSjogren",
        "id": 181346483,
        "node_id": "U_kgDOCs8gsw",
        "avatar_url": "...avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/181346483?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren",
        "html_url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren",
        "followers_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/followers",
        "following_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/orgs",
        "repos_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/repos",
        "events_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "...api.github.com/users/MaxSjogren/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
    },
    "created": false,
    "deleted": false,
    "forced": false,
    "base_ref": null,
    "compare": "...github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/compare/4ab5c24f8ce2...d191bc41b096",
    "commits": [
        {
            "id": "d191bc41b096d8a3535b4df28af94bc68a5700c2",
            "tree_id": "5ff6b097abc15006d362b38f6a80b3ee1dc09acb",
            "distinct": true,
            "message": "Update readme.md\n\nPILUTTA",
            "timestamp": "2024-10-01T12:55:11+02:00",
            "url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/commit/d191bc41b096d8a3535b4df28af94bc68a5700c2",
            "author": {
                "name": "MaxSjogren",
                "email": "BOFH'at'example.com",
                "username": "MaxSjogren"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "GitHub",
                "email": "noreply'at'github.com",
                "username": "web-flow"
            },
            "added": [],
            "removed": [],
            "modified": [
                "readme.md"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "head_commit": {
        "id": "d191bc41b096d8a3535b4df28af94bc68a5700c2",
        "tree_id": "5ff6b097abc15006d362b38f6a80b3ee1dc09acb",
        "distinct": true,
        "message": "Update readme.md\n\nPILUTTA",
        "timestamp": "2024-10-01T12:55:11+02:00",
        "url": "...github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic/commit/d191bc41b096d8a3535b4df28af94bc68a5700c2",
        "author": {
            "name": "MaxSjogren",
            "email": "BOFH'at'example.com",
            "username": "MaxSjogren"
        },
        "committer": {
            "name": "GitHub",
            "email": "noreply'at'github.com",
            "username": "web-flow"
        },
        "added": [],
        "removed": [],
        "modified": [
            "readme.md"
        ]
    }
}

My EventListener
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2024-09-30T09:39:43Z'
  generation: 6
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec': {}
      manager: kubectl-create
      operation: Update
      time: '2024-09-30T09:39:43Z'
    - apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec':
          'f:serviceAccountName': {}
          'f:triggers': {}
      manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      time: '2024-09-30T10:23:32Z'
    - apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          .: {}
          'f:address':
            .: {}
            'f:url': {}
          'f:conditions': {}
          'f:configuration':
            .: {}
            'f:generatedName': {}
      manager: openshift-pipelines-triggers-controller
      operation: Update
      subresource: status
      time: '2024-10-03T05:36:17Z'
  name: petclinic-eventlistener
  namespace: max-sjogren-dev
  resourceVersion: '4998716020'
  uid: 10a95c7d-1f54-417f-9b8f-c6799f58bf5d
spec:
  namespaceSelector: {}
  resources: {}
  serviceAccountName: pipeline
  triggers:
    - bindings:
        - kind: TriggerBinding
          ref: petclinic-triggerbinding
      name: petclinic-triggerbinding
      template:
        ref: petclinic-trigger-template
status:
  address:
    url: '...el-petclinic-eventlistener.max-sjogren-dev.svc.cluster.local:8080'
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2024-10-03T05:36:17Z'
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      status: 'True'
      type: Available
    - lastTransitionTime: '2024-10-03T05:36:17Z'
      message: Deployment exists
      status: 'True'
      type: Deployment
    - lastTransitionTime: '2024-09-30T10:23:40Z'
      message: ReplicaSet "el-petclinic-eventlistener-7486d66d4f" has successfully progressed.
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      status: 'True'
      type: Progressing
    - lastTransitionTime: '2024-10-03T05:36:17Z'
      message: EventListener is ready
      status: 'True'
      type: Ready
    - lastTransitionTime: '2024-10-03T05:36:17Z'
      message: Service exists
      status: 'True'
      type: Service
  configuration:
    generatedName: el-petclinic-eventlistener

Routes
$ oc get routes
NAME                         HOST/PORT                                                                              PATH   SERVICES                     PORT            TERMINATION          WILDCARD
el-petclinic-eventlistener   el-petclinic-eventlistener-max-sjogren-dev.apps.sandbox-m2.ll9k.p1.openshiftapps.com          el-petclinic-eventlistener   http-listener                        None

Name:           spring-petclinic-git
Namespace:      max-sjogren-dev
Created:        2 weeks ago
Labels:         app=spring-petclinic-git
                app.kubernetes.io/component=spring-petclinic-git
                app.kubernetes.io/instance=spring-petclinic-git
                app.kubernetes.io/name=spring-petclinic-git
                app.kubernetes.io/part-of=spring-petclinic-git-app
                app.openshift.io/runtime=java
                app.openshift.io/runtime-version=openjdk-17-ubi8
Annotations:    app.openshift.io/vcs-ref=
                app.openshift.io/vcs-uri=https://github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic.git
                openshift.io/generated-by=OpenShiftWebConsole
Latest Version: 1

Strategy:       Source
URL:            https://github.com/MaxSjogren/spring-petclinic.git
ContextDir:     /
From Image:     ImageStreamTag openshift/java:openjdk-17-ubi8
Volumes:        <none>
Output to:      ImageStreamTag spring-petclinic-git:latest

Build Run Policy:       Serial
Triggered by:           ImageChange, Config
Webhook Generic:
        URL:            https://api.sandbox-m2.ll9k.p1.openshiftapps.com:6443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/max-sjogren-dev/buildconfigs/spring-petclinic-git/webhooks/<secret>/generic
        AllowEnv:       false
Webhook GitHub:
        URL:    https://api.sandbox-m2.ll9k.p1.openshiftapps.com:6443/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/max-sjogren-dev/buildconfigs/spring-petclinic-git/webhooks/<secret>/github
Builds History Limit:
        Successful:     5
        Failed:         5

Build                   Status          Duration        Creation Time
spring-petclinic-git-1  complete        1m49s           2024-09-16 14:23:56 +0200 CEST

Events: <none>

I created a PipelineRun with following content
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1 
kind: PipelineRun 
metadata:
  name: petclinic-pipelinerun
  generateName: petclinic-pipelinerun-
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: petclinic-pipeline
  workspaces: 
  - name: max-sjogren-dev
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 500Mi

Now the eventlistener acctually trigers but I get different error.

[User error] PipelineRun max-sjogren-dev/petclinic-trigger-template-rbpn2
doesn't bind Pipeline max-sjogren-dev/petclinic-pipeline's Workspaces
correctly: pipeline requires workspace with name "max-sjogren-dev" be
provided by pipelinerun

Not sure if I should close this issue and create a new.
